# Issue in including libraries php

Tags: php, dompdf, amazon-ses

These are the libraries that i was trying to include

```
require_once("/var/www/html/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
require_once("/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php");
```

The first library is dompdf to save and print pdf output and second one is amazon SES library.

The code executes but dompdf classes are missing. This is the log

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DOMPDF' not found
```

But when i comment amazon SES library then dompdf works fine.

What is the possible issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: If the files are definitely being included properly, it could be a namespace issue. If you open each of the files you're including (or any of the sub-included files) see if there is a namespace being used.

Comment: Yes i saw namespace is amazon library. What is the remedy to tackle this issue.

Comment: Which version of dompdf are you using. You should be using at least 0.6.1 for better compatibility with other libraries/frameworks. The next version of dompdf will be namespaced.

Comment: Solved . Using latest version dompdf solved the issue.